# Which function do I use to read a text from file?

Tags: c, algorithm, file, dynamic, struct

Here's a text I want to load in this format to my terminal from a file

```
                                    nom                  : avatar
                                    type                 : Science_fiction
                                    l'annee de sortie    : 2012
                                    duree                : 120 minutes
                                    numero de reference  : 9

                                    nom                  : dark_knight
                                    type                 : Action
                                    l'annee de sortie    : 2008
                                    duree                : 124 minutes
                                    numero de reference  : 8
```

I tired using sscanf it works but every input takes a line not more

```
avatar Science_fiction 2012 120 9
dark_knight Action 2008 124 8
```

and here's my code

```
   #include<stdlib.h>
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<string.h>
   #include "structure_film.h"

   void load(struct film **head,struct film **current, FILE ** fichier,struct film **tail)

         char donnesDuFilm[255];

   struct film *premierfilm;premierfilm=(struct film*)malloc(sizeof(struct film));

    printf("le programme est en train de charger le catalogue depuis le fichier     catalogue\n");


   if (fgets(donnesDuFilm,255,*fichier)&&(strcmp(donnesDuFilm,"")))
    {


      sscanf(donnesDuFilm,"nom %s  type %s l'annee de sortie %d duree %d numero de reference %d\n",&premierfilm->nom,&premierfilm->typeFilm,&premierfilm->dateSortie,&premierfilm->duree,&premierfilm->id);

      printf("%s %s %d %d %d\n",premierfilm->nom,premierfilm->typeFilm,premierfilm->dateSortie,premierfilm->duree,premierfilm->id);


     *head=premierfilm;
    }
    while (fgets(donnesDuFilm,255,*fichier)&&(strcmp(donnesDuFilm,"")))
    {  
          struct film *nouveauFilm;

        nouveauFilm=(struct film*)malloc(sizeof(struct film));premierfilm->next=nouveauFilm;


        sscanf(donnesDuFilm,"nom %s  type %s l'annee de sortie %d duree %d numero de reference %d\n",&nouveauFilm->nom,&nouveauFilm->typeFilm,&nouveauFilm->dateSortie,&nouveauFilm->duree,&nouveauFilm->id);

        printf("%s %s %d %d %d\n",nouveauFilm->nom,nouveauFilm->typeFilm,nouveauFilm->dateSortie,nouveauFilm->duree,nouveauFilm->id);


        premierfilm=nouveauFilm;
        nouveauFilm->next=NULL;



    }

*current=premierfilm;*tail=premierfilm;


}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make at least a basic attempt to search before posting here. Chances are very good (particularly for beginner type questions like this one) that the question has already been asked and answered here before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

fscanf is the function you use to read from a text file. there should be loads about it on google considering it is a very common function. However first you need to make a file pointer, and use fopen.

```
char stringname[15]
FILE *filename = fopen("filelocation", r);
fscanf(filename, "%s", stringname);
```

Comment: I did make a file pointer FILE **fichier